# Using JPATH, how do I select a JSON value inside another JSON string?

Tags: json, json.net

I have the following JSON (simplified / minimized to show only pertinent parts) returned from a web service:

```
{
    "results": [{
        "paramName": "OutputPolyline",
        "dataType": "String",
        "value": "#{\"hasM\":true,\"paths\":[[[135.24,246.13,null],[135.24,246.13,null] ... [135.24,246.13,null]]]}"
    }],
    "messages": []
}
```

I use the following code to parse the JSON and grab the value of the "value" key:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
JToken token = obj.SelectToken("$.results[?(@.paramName == 'OutputPolyline')]['value']");

Console.WriteLine(token.Path + " -> " + token);
```

The above code returns the entire `value` string as expected, like such `"#{\"hasM\":true,\"paths\":[[[135.24,246.13,null],[135.24,246.13,null] ... [135.24,246.13,null]]]}"`

Building on the above code, how do I get only the value of the `paths` key? In this example, return only `[[[135.24,246.13,null],[135.24,246.13,null] ... [135.24,246.13,null]]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot extract the path values from the root object via a single [JsonPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) query since the value of the `value` property is just a string literal that happens itself to be re-serialized JSON.  It needs to be extracted and recursively parsed as JSON after first trimming off the `#` character, and Json.NET has no built-in [query operator](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JsonPath/QueryExpression.cs#L9) to do that as of the current version, 9.0.1.

Thus you need to do something like:

```
JToken token = obj.SelectToken("$.results[?(@.paramName == 'OutputPolyline')]['value']");

var paths = JToken.Parse(token.ToString().Trim('#')).SelectToken("paths");
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FL0Wpb).